# Can we create multiple dynamic timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

I need to create a windows service with multiple timer and timer number can't able to depreciate. Almost 40 timer need to create. Is that possible to dynamic timer. The number of timer needed will be loaded from DB. Is that advisable to create dynamic timers? If yes can we create dynamic timer in windows service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public static class AppTimer
{
    static AppTimer()
    {
        Events = new Dictionary<string, Event>();
    }

    public static Dictionary<string, Event> Events { get; set; }

    public static void AddEvent(string eventType, Event newEvent)
    {
        if (Events.ContainsKey(eventType))
        {
            Events[eventType].Timer.Stop();
            Events[eventType] = null;
            Events.Remove(eventType);
        }

        Events.Add(eventType, newEvent);
    }

    private static int CalculateTimerInterval(int minute)
    {
        if (minute < 0) minute = 60;

        var now = DateTime.Now;

        var future = new DateTime();

        // We want to run right away
        if (minute == 0)
        {
            future = now.AddSeconds(1.5);
        }
        else
        {
            future = now.AddMinutes((minute - (now.Minute%minute)))
                .AddSeconds(now.Second*-1)
                .AddMilliseconds(now.Millisecond*-1);
        }

        var interval = future - now;

        return (int)interval.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public class Event
    {
        public Event(Action tick, int interval)
        {
            this.Timer = new Timer { Interval = CalculateTimerInterval(interval) };
            this.Timer.AutoReset = false;
            this.Timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                    tick?.Invoke();

                if (this.Interval > 0)
                {
                    this.Timer.Interval = CalculateTimerInterval(this.Interval);
                }
            };
            this.Interval = interval;
            this.Timer.Start();
        }

        public Timer Timer { get; set; }

        public int Interval { get; set; }

        public void ChangeInterval(int newInterval)
        {
            this.Interval = newInterval;
            this.Timer.Interval = CalculateTimerInterval(newInterval);
        }
    }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
AppTimer.AddEvent("My Task #1", new AppTimer.Event(()=> { Console.WriteLine("Event Fired"); }, 1));
```

Comment: FYI, VS 2015 and C# 6 aren't public releases yet, so using the `?.` operator isn't completely kosher.